# How to decide dynamically which screen to transition to (iOS Game)

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I'm a little bit confused about how to best perform screen transitions in my game. I need to perform the following transitions [Main Menu] -> [Character Select] -> [Stage Select]

Up until now I was using Interface Builder to "click 'n drag" from a control in [Main Menu] to [Character Select] and choosing modal segue type. But then I realized that, on a second run of the game, the player doesn't need to go to [Character Select] screen again. Then I'd have the following flow [Main Menu] -> [Stage Select]

So my question(s) are:

1) Is modal transition the recommended way of doing this? All the examples I saw using modal transitions were to do popup or similar. I don't want to use Navigation Bars because I think those are not good design options for a game.

2) I saw somewhere I should not use segues here, instead I'd use "presentViewController:animated:completion:" but that led me to another set of questions.

3) In order to understand presentViewController... I ended up in the apple doc http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html 
which does not explain many things,

3.1) for instance how do I set the NIB file name of a Controller in Inteface Builder? (Do I have to create a .xib file). Actually this NIB/XIB file is very confusing.

I tried to pass in the name of the controller class as NIB name like this:

```
MyController* controller = [UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyController"...
```

but I get an exception "Could not load NIB in bundle..."

3.2) Also the document states I should set controller.delegate to self but UIController does not have a delegate property. Do I have to define a delegate property in the presented controller myself?

3.3) what about the second argument, "bundle", should I always pass in 'nil' or should I pass in mainBundle?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Kind of vague/broad. All these questions are very basic and are answered clearly in the documentation, tutorials, books, etc. But you can't expect to be taught all about nibs and storyboards and view controllers in a single question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a segue with a call to:

```
- (void)performSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
```

when you want to perform your `[Main Menu] -> [Stage Select]` transition.  Create a segue in your UIViewController subclass, configure it, and then use it as needed.

Alternately, in your view you already have a `UIControl` for the `[Main Menu] -> [Character Select]` you could:

1. change the segue it performs
2. disable it and hide it while enabling and unhiding a control for the `Menu->Stage` segue

Comment: Nice! I was having problems trying to create two segues from the same view but I realized how to do that. Thanks for answering the question and I apologize if I was vague about it.